# Evaluating polynomial using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create my own polynomial class. I want to make a function that can evaluate a polynomial where x is given.

So far I have this, however the answers its giving me aren't right and I cant figure out why?
The polynomials are inputted using a list. For example [2, 0, 1, -7, 13] would be 2x^4+x^2-7x+13

```
class Polynomial:

def __init__(self, coefficients):
    self.coeffs=coefficients

def evaluate(self, x):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(self.coeffs)-1,0,-1):
        sum+=self.coeffs[i]*(x**i)
    return sum
```

Comment: An example would be `p1 = Polynomial([2,3,4])` would evaluate to `p1(4) = 48`

Answer (score 0):

The `i` value you're using isn't right for both the index and the exponent. You're actually evaluating the reversed-coefficeint polynomial, so your evaluation results for `Polynomial([2,3,4])` are actually the right value for `Polynomial([4,3,2])`.

Here's how I'd define `evaluate`:

```
def evaluate(self, x):
    return sum(coef * x**exp for exp, coef in enumerate(reversed(self.coeffs)))
```

Note that if you want your `Polynomial` objects to be callable (as in `p1(4)` in the example in your comment), you should rename your `evaluate` function `__call__`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error expected an indented block for this code. To resole the error, be sure to include an indentation block:

```
class Polynomial:
    def __init__(self, coefficients):
        self.coeffs=coefficients

    def _call_(self, x):
    return sum(coef * x**exp for exp, coef in enumerate(reversed(self.coeffs)))
```